# How to custom order week year in power bi?

Tags: database, powerbi, dax, powerquery

I have issue in custom ordering data.
Here is example
[image: image showing how is data sorted]

I would like to be sorted first by year and than by week

I want 1 2022 to be at the and of the line.

I have tried adding few things.
Is there a way to sort this out by adding new table with weekYear column and some sortOrder column
which I have to populate with custom values as well?

I prefer solution to be dynamic..

If you have any solution please advice!

Answer (score 0):

I suggest

- Create a table from your column names
- Split the column by space delimiter
- Change column types to number
- sort by Year and then by Week
- Change column types to text
- combine the columns with space delimiter
- use this new, sorted list to re-order the original columns

I did this as a custom function:

```
(tbl as table, optional colsToSort as list) =>

let 
    colHdrs = if colsToSort=null then Table.ColumnNames(tbl) else colsToSort,
    hdrCol = Table.FromList(colHdrs,Splitter.SplitTextByDelimiter(" ")),
    
//type as number for sorting
    typeAsNumber = Table.TransformColumnTypes(hdrCol,{{"Column1", Int64.Type},{"Column2",Int64.Type}}),
    sorted = Table.Sort(typeAsNumber,{{"Column2", Order.Ascending}, {"Column1", Order.Ascending}}),

//type as text to combine
    typeAsText = Table.TransformColumnTypes(sorted,{{"Column1", Text.Type}, {"Column2", Text.Type}}),
    combine = Table.CombineColumns(typeAsText,{"Column1","Column2"},Combiner.CombineTextByDelimiter(" "),"orderHeaders"),

//re-Order the column headers in the original table
    newOrder = Table.ReorderColumns(tbl,combine[orderHeaders])
in 
    newOrder
```

And you could call it from your original query as:

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table13"]}[Content],
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{
        {"41 2021", Int64.Type}, {"42 2021", Int64.Type}, {"43 2021", Int64.Type}, 
        {"46 2021", Int64.Type}, {"1 2022", Int64.Type}, {"48 2021", Int64.Type}, 
        {"50 2021", Int64.Type}, {"49 2021", Int64.Type}, {"51 2021", Int64.Type}, 
        {"52 2021", Int64.Type}}),

//custom function here
    sortHdrs = fnSortHeaders(#"Changed Type")
in
    sortHdrs
```

[image]

*If ALL of your columns are in the format of `weeknumber year` so that you want to sort ALL of them, it may be simpler to do this without a separate function.  The advantage of the separate function is that you can more easily remove the column names you don't want to include in the sort*

*Here is code that will sort the column headers with no need of a separate function. It uses the same algorithm as above*

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table13"]}[Content],
    #"Changed Type2" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{
        {"41 2021", Int64.Type}, {"42 2021", Int64.Type}, {"43 2021", Int64.Type}, 
        {"46 2021", Int64.Type}, {"1 2022", Int64.Type}, {"48 2021", Int64.Type}, 
        {"50 2021", Int64.Type}, {"49 2021", Int64.Type}, {"51 2021", Int64.Type}, 
        {"52 2021", Int64.Type}}),
    
//create header list
//this assumes ALL column headers are to be sorted, but you can make partial lists for the column sorting
    hdrs = List.Combine(List.Transform(Table.ColumnNames(#"Changed Type2"), each Text.Split(_," "))),

//split into month and year and put into a table
    monthYear = Table.FromColumns({List.Alternate(hdrs,1,1,1),List.Alternate(hdrs,1,1,0)},{"Month","Year"}),

//change data type to number and sort by Year and then Month
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(monthYear,{{"Month", Int64.Type}, {"Year", Int64.Type}}),
    #"Sorted Rows" = Table.Sort(#"Changed Type",{{"Year", Order.Ascending}, {"Month", Order.Ascending}}),

//change data type to text and join with space delimiter
    #"Changed Type1" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Sorted Rows",{{"Month", type text}, {"Year", type text}}),
    sortedHeaders = Table.CombineColumns(#"Changed Type1",{"Month", "Year"},
        Combiner.CombineTextByDelimiter(" ", QuoteStyle.None),"newOrder")[newOrder],

//reOrder the original table
    sortedTableColumns= Table.ReorderColumns(#"Changed Type2",sortedHeaders)
in
    sortedTableColumns
```

Comment: I might got better solution for this one - 
'WeekYearSortOrder = 
VAR weeknum = 
    calendar[week]

RETURN
    Calendar[year] &
    SWITCH(
        TRUE(),
        weeknum <= 26,
        UNICHAR(weeknum + 64),
        weeknum <= 52,
        "Z" & UNICHAR(weeknum + 38),
        "ZZ" & UNICHAR(weeknum + 12)
    )'

what do you think

Comment: @nemd Your solution relies on DAX, mine is in M.  I would think that organizing and formatting the data is more of a task for Power Query than DAX (at least that's what I've read), but you should use whichever one works for you.